# Android studio crashes when opening any layout file

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm facing an issue on android studio program, I'm making some changes and fixing some bugs on android app that has been developed by an Indian company.
The problem is whenever I try to open any layout on this project android studio crashes and doesn't let me update any design file (only for this project).
However I can edit Java code but when it comes to xml it just crashes.
I tried this project in more than one computer, one of them had 32 GB of RAM and an I7 processor.
The project has a lot of libraries for a lot of stuff such as animations and so on.
Can you guys help me?

Here is a sample:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.fragments.SignUpFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/companyNameBox"
                    layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/lNameBox"
                    layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/serviceTypeSelectArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                        android:tint="#bfbfbf" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/serviceTypeEditBox"
                        layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" />
                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/emailBox"
                layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/passwordBox"
                layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobileNoArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/yearSelectArea"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/countrydropimage"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                        android:tint="#bfbfbf" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/countrydropimagerror"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                        android:tint="#bfbfbf"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/countryBox"
                        layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.30" />
                </FrameLayout>


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/mobileBox"
                    layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.70" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/inviteCodeArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/invitecodeBox"
                    layout="@layout/editbox_form_design"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.70" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/inviteQueryImg"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_help" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkboxTermsCond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#272727"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16" />

            <com.view.MTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTermsCond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_14"
                app:customTypeFace="roboto_light" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <include
            android:id="@+id/btn_type2"
            layout="@layout/btn_type_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/all_btn_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@color/appThemeColor_hover_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.view.MTextView
        android:id="@+id/signbootomHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Already have an account"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16"
        app:customTypeFace="roboto_light" />

    <com.view.MTextView
        android:id="@+id/signbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16"
        app:customTypeFace="roboto_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: Any xml file makes android studio crashes.

Comment: What android Studio  version your are using?, try to update it once

Comment: My version is 3.5.3

Comment: can you post crash log?

Comment: The problem is Android studio just stops, there is no message, logs or anything just stops and I have to open it again, I've been searching for this problem for 2 days.

Comment: share your xml code, will check

Comment: I edited the question with a code sample.

Comment: I'tried your xml, but not crashed, rendered prefectly

Comment: Regardless of whether or not that's the actual reason for the crash, I think you should try flattening out your layouts. Android Studio will allow up to 10 levels of embedded layouts before it starts warning you for performance issues. What you have here is has enough levels, custom views and included layouts to hinder your app's performance.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't use custome views like com.view.MTextView ?
What is flattening out my layouts?

Comment: Custom views are fine, but nesting so many layouts isn't. See if you can get rid of some by putting your elements inside a flat Constraint layout. Again though, that doesn't mean that this is the reason why your AS is crashing. Do you have any other layouts that are simpler that still crash your Studio? What happens if you try to create a new one? Are you able to edit that and see the Design tab?

Comment: You'e right, some layouts work fine but some others crash AS.

Comment: Oh, it just crashed again even with a simple layout that has only recyclerview!
I feel like the one who wrote this code has added sth that crashes AS so that no one will be able to modify it later

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem when opening a project ,did you try to :

1. file-->invalidate cashes/restart
2. delete .idea and .gradle
3. since it has a lot of libraries ,did you try to update dependencies (file-> project structure)
4. Downgrade your gradle tool version to 3.2.0

   dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
       }

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked for me.
I've had a headache from this problem :(

Comment: try to create a new activity for trial with a new xml layout ,and in your manifest file comment all the other activities except your new one and see if the app launches it or not ? Just to see if it is related to your xml files or not .